# Prove $\sin x=2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I prove the following identity?

$$\sin x=2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$$

I know $$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin a \cos b.$$

So I did

$$\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}.$$

But what technique would I have to use to continue the problem?

Comment: $\sin x = \sin (\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2}x) =$ ?

Comment: Apart from a typo, you are $99\%$ finished: $a+a=2a$.

Comment: Please do not write 1/2x in text, as it is not clear whether you want $\frac 1{2x}$ or $\frac x2$.  Either write x/2, (1/2)x, or, better, use $\LaTeX$

Comment: Is there a tutorial for this latex I think someone posted a link once....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$, letting $a = b = \frac{x}{2}$ gives $\sin x = \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} + \cos \frac{x}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2} = 2 (\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2})$.

Comment: Hmm would 2(sin(x/2)cos(x/2) equal sinX since 2sinXcosX=sin2X.

Comment: Of course. Let $X = \frac{x}{2}$. Also, you need to learn mathjax/latex.

Comment: I would but its kind of confusing to understand for me but I will try it.

Comment: The formula $\sin x = 2 (\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2})$ holds no matter what you replace the symbol $x$ with. Replace it by, for example, $2Y$, then you get back the formula: $\sin (2Y) = 2 \sin Y \cos Y$. Now replace $Y$ by $X$ or $x$ if you want.

Comment: Oh no I was talking about latex I understand your first comment.

Comment: Oops, I missed that :-).